# ¿Existe un equivalente de Web.Config en Angular 4/5?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, web.config

recién inicio en el desarrollo aplicaciones en Angular, de momento el path de conexión con el BackEnd (por ejemplo: 192.169.1.114:8080) lo tengo el app.module.ts. Pero me gustaría que ese path este en algún tipo de archivo de configuración tipo Web.Config de .Net, el cual existe cuando se generé el dist y poder ir ahí modificar el path sin tener que volver a generar el dist.

O si conocen una mejor manera para no tener ese path hardcodeado, me sería de gran ayuda la experiencia de alguien que conozca más el desarrollo en angular.

Muchas gracias de antemano comunidad.

Comment: El BackEnd es un WebApi de .Net. Por si sirve de algo.

Answer (score 1):

En la carpeta `app/environment/` encontraras 2 archivos llamados:

```
environment.prod.ts
environment.ts
```

Donde `environment.prod.ts` estara la configuracion de production y en `environment.ts` de desarrollo.

En desarrollo tendrias algo como:

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  url: '192.169.1.114:8080'
};
```

Y en `environment.prod.ts`:

```
export const environment = {
      production: true,
      url: 'https:/urlproduccion.com/api/'
    };
```

Entonces en tu codigo importas el objeto `environment`:

```
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';

this.http.get(environment.url)
...
```

Y CLI de angular sabra cual cargar segun el tipo build de la aplicacion si es `--prod` o desarrollo.

Comment: Es algo util, pero en mi caso seria lo mismo, tengo que volver a generar el dist, el detall es es que el equipo con el que trabajo constantemente cambia de IP y al cambiar a IP se pierde el acceso al backend.